# Typeorm - Disable default creation of columns id, createdAt, updatedAt when entity is synced

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, express-session

I am using typeorm with nest.js and I have a session entity like the below

```
import { Column, Entity, PrimaryColumn } from 'typeorm';
@Entity('session')
export class Session {
  @PrimaryColumn('varchar', { length: 255 })
  sid: string;

  @Column('jsonb')
  sess: JSON;

  @Column('timestamptz', { nullable: true })
  expire: string;
}
```

Whenever I start the server I have enabled `synchronize: true` in the configuration.

This is creating a table like the below, with id, createdAt, updatedAt being created by default even though not mentioned in the entity schema.

[image]

How to disable this default creation of (id, createdAt, updatedAt)columns and restrict the table to be created with only the columns I have mentioned in the entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably created by previous attempts. Try these steps to fix the issue:

1. Drop the database
2. run `npm run prebuild`
3. run `npm run build`
4. run `npm run start`